# Parsing a java Date back from toString()

Tags: java, parsing, date

I have a `String` containing the result of `toString()` called on an instance of `java.util.Date`. How can I parse this value back to a `Date` object?

The Java docs say that `toString()` converts this `Date` object to a `String` of the form:

```
 dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

but of course there is no such format tag as `"dow"` or `"mon"`.

Could someone please help me with this problem. Please note that unfortunately the `toString()` call is in a piece of code out of my control.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**If you don't have control over the code that's generating the String:**

To parse the `toString()` format you need to set the `SimpleDateFormat` locale to english and use the format: `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", new Locale("us"));`
```

Comment: Mm..as I said, I have no control over the toString(), since it is made by Struts. Anyway, setting the EN locale does the trick, so thank you. I just have to note that the right format string is "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", you had forgotten the Month.

Comment: I edited the answer to have it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test but something like this probably would work:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
```

If not, try to correct it using documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score -1):

Use simpledateformat. Find the doumentation here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score -1):

First take a look at all the date formats provided by java [Date Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
And you can use `SimpleDateFormat` class to do what you want.

```
 public class DateFormatTest 
    { 
      public DateFormatTest() 
      { 
        String dateString = // in "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy" format

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"); 
        Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString); 

        System.out.println("Converted string to date : " + convertedDate); 
      } 

      public static void main(String[] argv) 
      { 
        new DateFormatTest(); 
      } 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: "dow" and "mon" are not valid format specs

Answer (score -2):

Suppsoe you get String of "dateString" ;

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

Date date = sdf.parse("dateString");
```

Comment: This does not work and results in an exception being thrown. The correct constructor call is: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", new Locale("us"));`