# Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, jackson, format

`application.yml` configuration:

```
jackson:
    date-format: yyyy-MM-dd
    timestamp-format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

Bean properties:

```
@Entity 
@Column(nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date_created;

@Column(nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date reg_date;
```

I set all `Date` fields as `java.util.Date` type which receive date in format `yyyy-MM-dd`
and timestamp type(`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`) according to request param style(`yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`)

For using `timestamp`, I found the @Temporal(`TemporalType.Date` or `Timestamp`) which is mapping by `DB Type`.

Date and timestamp format is stored correctly like `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss`

`RestController` class:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestBody CreateVO createVO, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("planned_date> "+createVO.getDate_planned_start());
    System.out.println("regdate> "+createVO.getReg_date());    
}
```

Are set to:

```
planned_date> Wed Mar 20 09:00:00 KST 2019 // Date Result
regdate> Mon Oct 01 16:45:00 KST 2012 //Timestamp Result
```

However, I receive in RestController `Date` in different format than i expected.

Is there any solution to receive `yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in `Controller`?

I am wondering about `application.yml` settings as well. Because I am not sure how to set timestamp-format.

Comment: Are you expecting the `Date` in your entity and/or the `Date` returned from `getDate_planned_start` and `getReg_date` to have the format you have specified? That is not possible. A `Date` cannot have a format. Also you should not want to use the `Date` class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Don’t you want `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format) and/or [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format)

Answer (score 4):

First of all `Date.toString` method generates misleading output and we should not rely on it. Simple example:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateToStringFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", new Locale("us"));
Date parsed = dateToStringFormat.parse("Wed Mar 20 09:00:00 KST 2019");
System.out.println("Default toString: " + parsed);

dateToStringFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
System.out.println("With 'Asia/Seoul' TZ: " + dateToStringFormat.format(parsed));

dateToStringFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Chile/Continental"));
System.out.println("With 'Chile/Continental' TZ: " + dateToStringFormat.format(parsed));
```

prints:

```
Default toString: Wed Mar 20 01:00:00 CET 2019
With 'Asia/Seoul' TZ: Wed Mar 20 09:00:00 +0900 2019
With 'Chile/Continental' TZ: Tue Mar 19 21:00:00 -0300 2019
```

As you can see I parsed your example date `Wed Mar 20 09:00:00 KST 2019` and print using `toString` method and formatted with two different timezones. So, everyone sees date combined with his timezone. Read more about:

- [Java Date toString contains a timezone… Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951765/java-date-tostring-contains-a-timezone-why)
- [Parsing a java Date back from toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239814/parsing-a-java-date-back-from-tostring)

We can not define date patters in configuration like you proposed. See available [`Jackson` configuration options here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

You can configure format using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat` annotation. Since `Java 8` is available we should use `java.time.*` classes for time related properties. Example `POJO` class could like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.MonthDay;

public class RequestPayload {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd")
    private MonthDay md;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

To make it work we need to register [`JavaTimeModule`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) module:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.modules(new JavaTimeModule());

    return builder;
}
```

If you can change your `Bean` properties to `java.time.*` classes just propagate these dates from `Controller` to `DB`. In other case see this question: [Converting between java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date).

Comment: Thank you for answering but i don't want to use @JsonFormat or change Field from Date to LocalDate        i am looking for solution that Jackson configuration which receive (yyyy-MM-dd (request)> yyyy-MM-dd or yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss (request) > yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) through configuration in application .yml ..!

Comment: @SarahSon, I am afraid it is not possible to accept many date formats. You should pick the longest one and in case you want to send time just set zeroes. You can configure `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` with `builder.dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));` There is no option which allow to set date format for `Jackson` from configuration file like `application.yml`.