# Jackson @JsonFormat converting date with incorrect timezone

Tags: java, spring, date, jackson, annotations

I have a value coming in from JSON payload as:

```
"callStartTime" : "2019-03-27 13:00:00"
```

Entity.java

```
@JsonProperty("callStartTime")
@Column(name = "call_start_dt", nullable = false)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
private Date callStartTime;
```

When I printed it on console, it says:

```
Wed Mar 27 08:00:00 CDT 2019
```

I wanted to be the same as it was in json payload. How I can fix it?

I am just taking date from json and writing it to mysql db in a datetime column.

Comment: Take a look on this question: [Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256567/spring-boot-jackson-date-and-timestamp-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple solution:** I solved it by changing the data type to `String` which completes my aim to capture the value as it is coming from JSON payload. Using `Date` and other data types were converting the value to some different timezone.

```
@JsonProperty("callStartTime")
@Column(name = "call_start_dt", nullable = false)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
private **String** callStartTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
private Date callStartTime;
```

Comment: It's throwing exception.

 `exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2019-03-27T13:00:00Z": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`

Comment: Ah You don't have milliseconds in your date use 
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.XXX

Comment: If you use java version >= 1.8 use ZonedDateTime instead of Date
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.XXX")
private ZonedDateTime callStartTime;

Comment: Still it throws an exception. same as above mentioned

Answer (score -1):

[java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) does not capture time zone data. It only knows about number of millis since the epoch.

You could try using one of the modules in [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) and deserialize into an instance of [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead, which is time-zone aware.

EDIT: try this as a basis for getting it to work:

```
public class SoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                                            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        String s = "{\"callStartTime\" : \"2019-03-27T13:00:00Z\" }";

        MyType mt = om.readValue(s, MyType.class);

        System.out.println(mt.getCallStartTime());
    }
}

class MyType {
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
    private ZonedDateTime callStartTime;

    public ZonedDateTime getCallStartTime() {
        return callStartTime;
    }

    public void setCallStartTime(ZonedDateTime date) {
        this.callStartTime = date;
    }

}
```

Comment: Got an exception.
`Cannot deserialize value of type java.time.ZonedDateTime from String "2019-03-27T13:00:00Z": Text '2019-03-27T13:00:00Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type java.time.ZonedDateTime from String "2019-03-27T13:00:00Z": Text '2019-03-27T13:00:00Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19`

Comment: Also added the all 3 dependencies mentioned in [jackson-modules-8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)

Comment: I am not using ObjectMapper. How do it register it?
I am just taking date from json and writing it to mysql db in a datetime column.

Comment: Your use of @JsonProperty (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) suggests that something somewhere is using Jackson to do JSON parsing which in turn means ObjectMapper is being used.

Comment: okay got it. But still getting this exception. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Try using "@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)" - note the Z, to capture timezone (Zulu in the example case you gave above)

Comment: OK - added a small working test. Looks like X was needed, not Z, for your format per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score -1):

There are two possible solutions for this :

**1. Define ObjectMapper bean and set date format.**

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper()
{
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   objectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
       return objectMapper;
}
```

**2. Set date format for the particular field using @JsonFormat**

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
private Date createTime;
```