# Constants for JsonFormat's pattern option

Tags: java, jackson, date-formatting

In our code we currently use the Jackson `@JsonFormat` annotation on a date object as follows:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ")
private Date startDate;
```

Is there a class which defines constants for these patterns in order to avoid having such hardcoded value? Something like:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DateTimePatterns.ISO_DATETIME_TIMEZONE)
private Date startDate;
```

Or should I just create my own constants-class?

Comment: If it is possible you should use `Java 8` `Time` package. See: [Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256567/spring-boot-jackson-date-and-timestamp-format/55270120#55270120), [Converting between java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date). If you do not use this pattern in many places there is no point to extract it somewhere. If you use, create your own class with constant.